# Adding a string to a list throws Integer NFE on double * parsed int

Tags: java, string

I've got a list of strings I'm putting together.

```
        x = "1"; 
        Integer.parseInt(x);                          //does not throw an exception
        out.add((43.244 * Integer.parseInt(x)) + ""); //throws an exception
```

Is throwing

```
        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "43.244"
```

My understanding of Java is that Integer should be widened to Double, multiplied, and converted to string with +""

Is there something I'm misunderstanding here?

EDIT:

Truncated Stack Trace

```
    .... FXML trace ....
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "43.244"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
     ... etc ...
```

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: Post the exact exception you are getting, including Stack Trace.

Comment: The entire stack trace is about 40 lines of FXML stack, the exception is otherwise just the truncated backtrace from the line above and the Integer class failures.  The next line is referencing that line, the line after is the calling method, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

An `Integer` will never widened to a `Double`.  You may be thinking that an `int` can be widened to a `double`, which is true.  But `Integer.parseInt` specifically looks for a text pattern to fit an `int`.  Only when `Integer.parseInt` returns an `int` will the `*` operator widen it to a `double` for multiplication.

Use `Double.parseDouble` instead, to generate the `double` directly, since `"43.244"` isn't a representation of an `int`, but of a `double`.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware that widening was only for the primitives.

Clarifying that the parse-int is failing because it's inside of an expression that expects a Double?

Because x is an integer that is lifted from a string.

Presuming that Integer.parseInt returns an int at all, I'd expect Double * int to widen.

Comment: No, it's failing because Integer.parseInt will always fail given a String that represents a decimal number, regardless of context.  Only when it succeeds will the int be widened to a double.

Comment: Integer.parseInt isn't parsing a decimal number.  If you look at the error message, the parsing problem is cited as being the double literal, not the string variable being parsed as int.

Comment: Something is passing `"43.244"` to `Integer.parseInt`, hence the exception.

Comment: The original code you posted didn't have `x = "1";` at the top, so the assumption was that `x = "43.244";`.  The only thing I can think of is that some code you haven't shown is responsible for the NFE.  Please include more of your stack trace, at least down to the first line that represents code you've written, and any other relevant code, because the current code you've shown won't produce a NFE.